# Excelデータで条件に合致しないデータを除外して取り込む方法

Tags: python, pandas, excel

## やりたいこと

エクセルファイルの特定シート（シート名前が決まっている）を読み込み、取り込むべきデータかを判断したいです。
例えば以下のような条件で不適合なデータを除く（適合するデータを抽出する）こと。

- 必須項目で空白はNG
- Noは1以上
- Modelは既定の文字列以外はNG
- TypeがCのときにはoption文字列必須でなければNG

Excelファイルを取り込むのにpandasを利用しましたが、特にpandasである必要はないです。

## 質問内容

- pandasを利用して、DataFrameとして取り込んだ場合、条件付けして上記の抽出するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？→ for文を回して条件付けするしかないでしょうか。
- このような用途ならpandas+openpyxlではないほうが良いでしょうか？

## 環境

Windows 10
Python 3.9.10

## 利用パッケージ

pandas
openpyxl

### データサンプル

実際はエクセルシートで、[]部分は空白だと解釈して下さい。

```
No,Name,Model,type,option
1,D001,[],A,[]
-1,D002,N-1,B,[]
2,D003,N-2,C,aaa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

# 必須項目
required = ['No', 'Name', 'type']
# Model: 規定の文字列
models = ['N-1', 'N-2']

idx = df[required].notna().all(axis=1)
dfx = df[idx].query('No >= 1 and Model in @models and (type != "C" or option.notna())')
print(dfx)

#    No  Name Model type option
# 2   2  D003   N-2    C    aaa
```